# Trouble upgrading from GWT 1.5 to 1.6; What to change in maven setup?

Tags: maven-2, gwt, upgrade

I've tried to upgrade a working GWT 1.5.2 application to 1.6.4 using maven to build. After fixing all errors and updating all deprecated calls, it compiles nicely.

But when I try to start the application nothing happens, because (according to Firebug) the files I try to download is

```
http://localhost:8080/softwarename/com.myCompany.WorkSpace/undefined
```

obviously the file loaded right before this (`http://localhost:8080/softwarename/com.myCompany.WorkSpace/com.myCompany.WorkSpace.nocache.js`) is trying to GET a file definied in a `null` string.

What do I need to change in the setup (pom.xml, structure etc.) to make it work? Google hasn't helped...

UPDATE:
I've seem to have found the solution. The migration instructions worked with a few modifications. I had to create the directory in the war directory with the name from the `rename-to` attribute.

Beacause maven didn't get the WorkSpace.html from the war directory but got it from the public directory i had to remove the folder from the path of the script block. I allso had to change the spring security filter paths because the url has changed from `http://localhost:8080/softwarename/com.myCompany.WorkSpace/WorkSpace.html` to `http://localhost:8080/softwarename/workspace/WorkSpace.html` (where `workspace` is the rename-to value).

Now I just have to get the RPC calls to work again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have been caught out by the new Project structure in GWT 1.6.  Basically some of your files need to be in different places.

I followed the [migration instructions in the GWT 1.6 Release Notes](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/ReleaseNotes_1_6.html) to get my code working.

We don't use Maven so I'm afraid I can't help you there.

Comment: Yeah, I figured the changes to the file hierarchy was a possible cause, but I'm not sure how to implement the changes so that maven "understands" it.